# Nested rolling sum in vector

Tags: r, performance, vector

I am struggling to produce an efficient code to compute the vector result `r` result from an input vector `v` using this function.

```
    r(i) = \sum_{j=i}^{i-N} [o(i)-o(j)] * exp(o(i)-o(j))
```

where `i` loops (from N to M) over the vector `v`. Size of `v` is `M>>N`.

Of course this is feasible with 2 nested for loops, but it is too slow for computational purposes, probably out of fashion and deprecated style...

A MWE:

```
for (i in c(N+1):length(v)){
  csum <- 0
  for (j in i:c(i-N)) {
      csum <- csum + (v[i]-v[j])*exp(v[i]-v[j]) 
      }
  r[i] <- csum
}
```

In my real application `M > 10^5` and the `v` vector is indeed several vectors.

I have been trying with nested applications of lapply and rollapply without success.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar enough that it's not worth an additional answer, but another `sapply` might be: `res <- sapply(v[N:length(v)], function(x, y) sum((x - y)*(exp(x - y))), y = v[1:5]);
res <- c(rep(NA, 4), res)`.

Comment: @abmo, is `j in 1:N` a mistake? Do you want `j in 1:i`?

Comment: @ChiPak nope, it's not. I am really cumulating the difference of N data from the position in "i". And doing this for i in 1 to M. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Cath, Mike and Imo for your suggestions: an example of simple, efficient and beautiful R code. Thanks.

Comment: @abmo, Note your original code `v[i]-v[j]` will calculate the difference between the `ith` entry and entries `v[1:5]` since `j` is `1:N` where `N=5`. **Not** `v[1:i]` **nor** `v[(i-5):i]`. Please advise...In addition, `i` loops from `N:M`, **not** `1:M`, but I think you mean `N:M`.

Comment: @ChiPak thanks... I was too in a rush... you are right and my mwe is not fully correct. I will amend my post and look through the solutions proposed so far to see if they will still fit my needs. Thanks Chi Pak.

Comment: Yes, note that the solutions below can be amended easily but currently use `v[1:5]` because of your original code.

Comment: Could you (re-)provide a more complete example? It seems like you are, essentially, computing: `difs = outer(-v[1:N], v[N:length(v)], "+"); c(rep_len(NA, N - 1), colSums(difs * exp(difs)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is any more efficient but something you can try:

```
r[N:M] <- sapply(N:M, function(i) tail(cumsum((v[i]-v[1:N])*exp(v[i]-v[1:N])), 1))
```

checking that both computations give same results, I got `r` with your way and `r2` with mine, initializing `r2` to `rep(NA, M)` and assessed the similarity:

```
all((r-r2)<1e-12, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```

**NOTE:** as in @lmo answer, `tail(cumsum(...), 1)` can be efficiently replaced by just using `sum(...)`:

```
r[N:M] <- sapply(N:M, function(i) sum((v[i]-v[1:N])*exp(v[i]-v[1:N])))
```

Comment: I tested your method compared to `lmo` and `MikeH` and it's actually one of the slowest, perhaps because of `cumsum`. Could you amend your answer, and give as an alternative the same `sapply` statement but with `sum`? This gives a speedup of about 5-fold on a 10,000 length vector. Simply compare `system.time(original statement)` to the new statement to see for yourself.

Comment: @ChiPak Yes very likely due to that, I've edited with the line using `sum`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method with a single `for` loop.

```
# create new blank vector
rr <- rep(NA,M)

for(i in N:length(v)) {
  rr[i] <- sum((v[i] - v[seq_len(N)]) * exp(v[i] - v[seq_len(N)]))
}
```

check for equality

```
all.equal(r, rr)
[1] TRUE
```

You could reduce the number of operations by 1 if you store the difference. This should add a little speed up.

```
for(i in N:length(v)) {
  x <- v[i] - v[seq_len(N)]
  rr[i] <- sum(x * exp(x))
}
```

Comment: quite similar, you're being smarter than me using `sum` instead of `tail(cumsum(...), 1)`! ;-) (I did not put enough thinking on this part)

Comment: Thanks, `sapply` may be a bit faster in the looping, though.